# Costume world fail to load in Hector_quadrotor_gazeboo

Tags: gazebo-world

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

hi there. I am trying to load a costume world for Hector_quadrotor_gazebo , lets say *3.world* which is basically `roslaunch hector_quadrotor_gazebo quadrotor_empty_world.launch` then added some buildings and objects and saved the new world as 3.world.

how can launch this world later on ? i had followed the tutorial in 'http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/03/6/' which worked fine for turtlebot but didnt work for hector_quadrotor.

iam new to ROS and Gazebo so excuse my question.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18891/costume-world-fail-to-load-in-hector_quadrotor_gazeboo/) by [Caesar84](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4875/caesar84/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So if you look at the contents of the `quadrotor_empty_world.launch` take note of the following section:

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
  <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
  <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
  <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
  <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
</include>
```

This .launch file passes arguments to gazebo_ros's empty_world.launch file. If you look at the empty_world.launch file, you'll see the following line:

```
<arg name="world_name" default="worlds/empty.world"/> <!-- Note: the world_name is with respect to GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH environmental variable -->
```

This line means that you can pass this file a world_name argument to open any .world file you'd like.

So to answer your question, add a line (or make a copy if you don't want to change the original file) to the quadrotor_empty_world.launch file like so:

```
<include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
  <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
  <arg name="use_sim_time" value="$(arg use_sim_time)"/>
  <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
  <arg name="headless" value="$(arg headless)"/>
  <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
  <arg name="world_name" value="path/to/3.world"/>
</include>
```

And then obviously input the correct path to your 3.world file.

---

Originally posted by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) with karma: 376 on 2018-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0